# Java Web Start cannot be started after upgrading JRE j2se 1.8.0_181

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

Application Blocked by Deployment Rule Set

For security, applications must now meet the requirements for the High or Very High security settings, or be part of the Exception Site List, to be allowed to run.

More:
https://java.com/de/download/help/jcp_security.xml

Deployment Rule Set required Java version 1.8.0_60 is not available or incompatible with version 1.8+ requested by the Application.

Questions:

- How can I add deployment rule set properly to allow starting JWS properly? Updating `version` attribute cannot help
- I can still start downloaded app from cache. The standard tool to manage locally installed apps looks sporadically. Is there advanced alternatives?
- Looking for C#/Java librarian code to manage/start JWS apps from cache

Comment: Questions added. Another one: can this new awesome feature handle with Java Web Start deprecation?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/threerings/getdown/issues/132#issuecomment-418614563